# Mac Chrome freezes on startup

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac, freeze

When Chrome starts up fresh, the initial tab and any new tabs freeze for about 10-15 minutes, then suddenly start working. It's very frustrating. I've tried just about everything I can think of.

- `--disable--extension`
- removed `/Application/Google Chrome.app`
- removed `~/Library/Application Support/Google`

I'm out of ideas. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Chrome v55 and Chrome Canary v56.  Mac El Cap and Sierra (just upgraded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting Chrome's cache should resolve this issue.

Delete this folder: `~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome` (make a backup first).